# How do I fill a selection using a pre defined pattern with photoshop scripting

Tags: scripting, photoshop

How do I fill a selection using a pre defined pattern with photoshop scripting

```
var docRef = app.documents.add()

var layerRef =docRef.layerSets.add();

layerRef.kind = LayerKind.PATTERNFILL;

docRef.selection.selectAll();

docRef.selection.fill(pattern?);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a pattern ID - the simplest way to do that is to use the scriptListener and find out with a quick test fill and check the listener code.  Here's an example:

```
var myPattern = "d5706459-5277-11e7-aad4-ff82069d78d5";
fill_with_pattern(myPattern)

function fill_with_pattern(patternID)
{
    var idFl = charIDToTypeID( "Fl  " );
    var desc1283 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
    var idFlCn = charIDToTypeID( "FlCn" );
    var idPtrn = charIDToTypeID( "Ptrn" );
    desc1283.putEnumerated( idUsng, idFlCn, idPtrn );
    var idPtrn = charIDToTypeID( "Ptrn" );
    var desc1284 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idNm = charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " );
    desc1284.putString( idNm, """40x40""" ); // id name
    var idIdnt = charIDToTypeID( "Idnt" );
    desc1284.putString( idIdnt, patternID );
    var idPtrn = charIDToTypeID( "Ptrn" );
    desc1283.putObject( idPtrn, idPtrn, desc1284 );
    var idOpct = charIDToTypeID( "Opct" );
    var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );
    desc1283.putUnitDouble( idOpct, idPrc, 100.000000 ); //opacity
    var idMd = charIDToTypeID( "Md  " );
    var idBlnM = charIDToTypeID( "BlnM" );
    var idNrml = charIDToTypeID( "Nrml" );
    desc1283.putEnumerated( idMd, idBlnM, idNrml );
    executeAction( idFl, desc1283, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

I think you can call a pattern by name instead of it's ID - but I've not managed do it successfully. If you try with a pre-existing pattern, like Bubbles you'll get code like this:

```
desc1297.putString( idNm, """$$$/Presets/Patterns/Patterns_pat/Bubbles=Bubbles""" );
var idIdnt = charIDToTypeID( "Idnt" );
desc1297.putString( idIdnt, """b7334da0-122f-11d4-8bb5-e27e45023b5f""" );
```